# SQL запрос для поиска записей с середины таблицы

Tags: php, sql

Прошу помощи в поиске решения, ибо сам найти его не сумел.
Есть таблица товаров (`id`, `title`, `category`), на страницу вывожу по 50 записей: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > (($page-1)*50) LIMIT 50`, где `$page` – номер текущей страницы. Я с легкостью могу вычислить значение `id`, для любого номера страницы, при условии, что номера `id` идут последовательно.

Проблема получается в случае, если `id` записей идут не последовательно, а с разрывами нумерации. Например, мне нужно выбрать несколько категорий, `id` между которыми теряют итерацию +1.

Как я могу вычислить номер третей страницы (на странице по 50 записей), если мне необходимо выбрать две категории, `id` которых: 100-170 и 200-300. Третья страница будет начинаться с `id` = 229. Как мне вычислить данное число, для того, чтобы подставить его в SQL запрос `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id >= 229 LIMIT 50`.
Буду очень признателен за вашу помощь!

Примитивно решая задачи, я выполнял SQL запрос без `LIMIT` в массив PHP, а потом в зависимости от номера страницы находил нужную мне ячейку массива. Данный способ работал на локальном сервере, но не на сервере сайта, там как запрос на более чем 10000 записей не срабатывает. И это решение ресурсо-затратное.

Comment: В цикле запомнить последний id, к примеру...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак не вычислять.

Выбранный вами способ пагинации не подразумевает вывод ссылок на произвольные страницы, а только ссылок "Предыдущая/Следующая". И, соответственно, по ссылке "Следующая" передается максимальный id текущей страницы.

Если хочется выводить номера страниц (хотя непонятно - зачем, поскольку их заведомо будет очень много, и все равно придется сокращать), то используйте традиционную пагинацию c `LIMIT .. OFFSET`.

Для ускорения традиционной пагинации можно выбирать только id товаров и создать индекс, который содержит все используемые в выборке поля. В данном случае это будет id категории. А затем уже выбирать сами товары по списку полученных id для страницы, через `WHERE id IN (..)`.

То есть сначала делаете запрос

```
SELECT count(*) FROM goods WHERE category_id in (1,2)
```

И получаете обще количество записей для вывода ссылок на страницы.

после этого делаете запрос

```
SELECT id FROM goods WHERE category_id in (1,2) ORDER BY ID LIMIT 50 OFFSET ?
```

Где в плейсхолдер ? передаете смещение страницы. При наличии составного индекса по (id, category_id) этот запрос будет выполнен очень быстро, поскольку БД будет перебирать не записи на диске, а уже упорядоченный индекс, который уже лежит в памяти.

Ну и дальше полученные id подставить в запрос

```
SELECT * FROM goods WHERE id in (...) ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Как вариант, наверное будет проще сделать кнопки "далее", "назад". Сайт будет работать быстрее, но не так красиво получится.